# Finding a basis for which the representation of a bilinear form is diagonal using row and column operations

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

> Find a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ for which the representation of
>   $$F(x,y) = x^T\begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & 1 & 2 & 0  \\
>     1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
>     2 & 1 & 3 & -1 \\
>     0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
>     \end{bmatrix} y$$
>   is diagonal, and write the matrix of $F$ with respect to this basis (Use row and column operations).

I think by converting the matrix into it's quadratic form and by using Sylvester's Law of Inertia or completing the square method, we can find the basis by orthogonalization-like process. But I have no idea how the basis can be found by using row and column operations. I saw some similar questions here but most of them are solved by the use of Eigen-values and since we don't know that topic yet, there is probably a different solution method. Any hint or help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: completing the square and the algorithm I show below are the same thing, except that one reports my matrix $P$ first, and the other way reports my matrix $Q = P^{-1}$ first. I am careful to write out how to  produce both at the same time... As you will see, your quadratic form is the just difference of two squares.

Comment: The "row and column operations" are accomplished by a sequence of elementary matrices $E_j$ and each "operation" as $$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see, it comes out that the original polynomial, let us write it in variables $w,x,y,z,$ is a difference of squares, meaning it also factors as the product of two linear forms. This is sufficiently unusual (with everything integers) that I would bet the question was constructed using the factoring.

$$ (w+x+2y)^2 - (x+y+z)^2 = \; \;  (w + 2x + 3y + z)(w+y-z) $$ 
Notice how the product makes obvious the $3y^2,$ also $-z^2,$ but zero $x^2$ terms.

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

====================================================

algorithm: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ D_0 = H $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
2 &  - 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Very detailed answer and really nice references. Thank you very much :)